# Elixir/Phoenix - get current time (Timex library)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, timex

I use Timex library for getting current time. For example:

```
iex(9)> time = Timex.now
~U[2019-11-29 14:05:39.759000Z]
```

When I take the minute, I get the following

```
iex(10)> time.minute
5
```

If the current minute is up to 10, then I get a value without a leading zero (the same with hours and seconds).
I can get the length of the resulting value and, if it's less than 2, add a zero at the beginning, but I think this is not the best solution

Comment: Why would you need `Timex` to get the current time in 2019 btw?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I also need to get the names of the day of the week. As far as I know, using standard elixir functions, this cannot be obtained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`time.minute |> Integer.to_string |> String.pad_leading(2, "0")`

Comment: `String.pad_leading("#{time.minute}", 2, "0")`?